# Pourquoi est-ce que l'on dit "je m'y sens obligé" et non "je m'en sens obligé"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en, y

Il y a une semaine, j'ai eu une conversation avec un Français qui m'a corrigé. Je voulais dire "je me sens obligé de faire ..." de façon briève et je disais alors "je m'en suis obligé" parce qu'il y a un "de", mais il disait que ça devait être "je m'y sens obligé", ce qui ne me semble pas du tout logique. Après, je lui ai demandé si on peut dire alors "se sentir obligé à faire qqch", mais ça ne se dit pas. La même chose vaut pour une construction avec "être obligé" : "j'y suis obligé" et non "j'en suis obligé".

En recherchant un peu sur Internet, j'ai trouvé que l'on peut dire par exemple "je m'en sens capable", ce qui est tout à fait la même construction sauf pour l'adjectif. J'ai vraiment des difficultés à saisir cette particularité.

Est-ce que c'est une exception ou est-ce qu'il existe une règle pour cette construction ?
Merci d'avance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C'est une exception spécifique aux verbes *forcer, obliger* et *contraindre* (Le Bon usage, 14e ed., §908 a) 8°). Ces verbes ont la particularité qu'en conjugaison active, l'object indirect se construit avec *à*, mais sous forme de participe adjectif ou composé avec *être* (par example au passif), ils se construisent plutôt avec *de*.

Si *à* apparaît dans le cas où l'objet indirect est réduit à un pronom, c'est probablement parce que c'est la forme que prend l'objet dans la constructive active "de base" (*je m'**y** oblige*).

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Votre réponse est tout à faire claire ! :D

Comment: Excusez-moi, *fait